# How to reorder columns in a datagrid Dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I am using `autogeneratecolumns ="false"` and using some template fields.

It works when I use:

```
tempColumnNew = Me.DataGrid.Columns(oldColIndex)
tempColumnOld = Me.DataGrid.Columns(newColIndex)

Me.DataGrid.Columns.RemoveAt(oldColIndex)
Me.DataGrid.Columns.RemoveAt(newColIndex)

Me.DataGrid.Columns.AddAt(oldColIndex, tempColumnOld)
Me.DataGrid.Columns.AddAt(newColIndex, tempColumnNew)
```

But it doesnt remember the added columns on postback, so I have to add them for every postback.

Is there a better way to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                    This code worked for me:
                    oldColIndex = Me.DataGrid.Columns.IndexOf(col)
                    tempColumnNew = Me.DataGrid.Columns(oldColIndex)
                    tempColumnOld = Me.DataGrid.Columns(newColIndex)

                    Me.DataGrid.Columns.AddAt(oldColIndex, tempColumnOld)
                    Me.DataGrid.Columns.RemoveAt(oldColIndex + 1)
                    Me.DataGrid.Columns.AddAt(newColIndex, tempColumnNew)
                    Me.DataGrid.Columns.RemoveAt(newColIndex + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [IsPostBack](http://www.aspnet101.com/2007/03/if-not-page-ispostback/) on the Page_Load event?

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
  tempColumnNew = Me.DataGrid.Columns(oldColIndex)
  tempColumnOld = Me.DataGrid.Columns(newColIndex)

  Me.DataGrid.Columns.RemoveAt(oldColIndex)
  Me.DataGrid.Columns.RemoveAt(newColIndex)

  Me.DataGrid.Columns.AddAt(oldColIndex, tempColumnOld)
  Me.DataGrid.Columns.AddAt(newColIndex, tempColumnNew)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply....
I am using ispostback, but this code is in the Binddata method.....
which is called to bind the data to the datagrid.......